# What does / in the regular expression mean?

Tags: javascript, regex

I came across some legacy code where we are trying to do exact matches against strings using javascript regex.

I am trying to understand why they are using / before and after the match string.

example

```
 var match = thinger.match(/stringToMatch/);
```

What does this character do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/regex here/` is a means of declaring a regular expression in javascript.

The `/` character is a delimiter for a regular expression declaration much like a single or double quote is a delimiter for a string declaration.

See the [MDN regular expression reference page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for a written description.  A regex can be declared either of these two ways in javascript:

```
var re = /match string here/i;
var re = new RegExp("match string here", "i");
```

The advantages of using the `/regex here/` method are:

1. You can freely use quotes in the match without having to escape them, though you have to escape a `/` in the reg when using this method
2. It's less typing and more compact

The advantages of using the `new RegExp("regex here")` method are:

1. You can use javascript expressions to dynamically construct the string or regex arguments as in `new RegExp("first" + foo + "whatever")` which you cannot do with the other method.
2. You don't have to worry about escaping forward slashes

Comment: Good answer, +1. @MedicineMan: The technical term for the slashes is "delimiter".

Comment: @iain - Thx.  I added "delimiter" to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`/` is [the regexp literal delimiter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_Regular_Expression), analogous to [`'` and `"` as string delimiters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Syntax).

Answer (score 1):

It is the delimiter for a [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). Just like you can create a new primitive string by typing `'string'` instead of invoking its constructor `new String('string')`, so you can specify a RegExp with `/regexp/` rather than `new RegExp('regexp')`.

Answer (score 0):

They are delimiters specifying the beginning and end of the regex.  You can also append operators such as /i to make a regex case independent.

Comment: The "operators" are normally called "flags"